# No se ejecuta función de scroll automatico

Tags: javascript, html, html5, dom

Según yo, debería ejecutarse la función

> scroll();

para llegar al final de la página, esto al momento en el que el elemento canvas es creado, pero esto no sucede, y tampoco marca algún error

```js
const options = document.getElementById('options');
const clasic = document.getElementById('clasico');

function addClasic() {
  clasic.classList.add('down-up');

  setTimeout(() => {
    removeEl();
    createEl(clasic);
  }, 2700);

  scroll();
}

function removeEl() {
  while (options.firstChild) {
    options.removeChild(options.firstChild);
  }
}

function createEl() {
  const lienzo = document.createElement('canvas');
  const points = document.createElement('div');

  lienzo.setAttribute('id', 'snake_canvas');
  points.setAttribute('id', 'points');
  points.setAttribute('class', 'top-rigth');
  options.appendChild(lienzo);
  options.appendChild(points);
}

//esta funcion no se ejecuta
function scroll() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body').scrollTop = 600;
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
.title {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

.title-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5.5em;
}

.clasico-mode {
  border-radius: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #e50d4c;
}

#clasico-text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.8em;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

.down-up {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: down-up;
}

#snake_canvas {
  width: 1205px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 3px #000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

@keyframes down-up {
  25% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(125px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-755px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <p class="title-text">Snake</p>
</div>

<div id="options" class="modes">
  <div id="clasico" class="clasico-mode" onclick="addClasic()">
    <p id="clasico-text">clasico</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eliminé la sig. funcion

> function scroll() {
>     setTimeout(() => {
>       document.getElementsByTagName('body').scrollTop = 600;
>     }, 500);
>   }

coloqué el sig. código en el setTimeout() de la funcion addClasic() para hacer el scroll hasta el fina de la página

> window.scroll(0, window.innerHeight);

```js
const options = document.getElementById('options');
const clasic = document.getElementById('clasico');

function addClasic() {
  clasic.classList.add('down-up');

  setTimeout(() => {
    removeEl();
    createEl(clasic);
    window.scroll(0, window.innerHeight);
  }, 2700);
}

function removeEl() {
  while (options.firstChild) {
    options.removeChild(options.firstChild);
  }
}

function createEl() {
  const lienzo = document.createElement('canvas');
  const points = document.createElement('div');

  lienzo.setAttribute('id', 'snake_canvas');
  points.setAttribute('id', 'points');
  points.setAttribute('class', 'top-rigth');
  options.appendChild(lienzo);
  options.appendChild(points);
}
```

```css
.title {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

.title-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5.5em;
}

.clasico-mode {
  border-radius: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #e50d4c;
}

#clasico-text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.8em;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

.down-up {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: down-up;
}

#snake_canvas {
  width: 1205px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 3px #000;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

@keyframes down-up {
  25% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(125px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-755px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <p class="title-text">Snake</p>
</div>

<div id="options" class="modes">
  <div id="clasico" class="clasico-mode" onclick="addClasic()">
    <p id="clasico-text">clasico</p>
  </div>
</div>
```